# Doubts on conductor and insulator

Tags: experimental-physics, conductors, humidity

I read on Stephen Gray's discovery of conductor and insulator. From that I came across a question that how cork, wood, rope can act as conductor being an insulator but then I got the answer that it is because of the humidity.

But that answer made me more confused. You must be thinking why? 
If humidity can make those insulator to act as conductor then other insulator assume silk that might have been used in Stephen Gray's experiment must act as a conductor as a result there will only be the discovery of conductor then how he discovered insulator (as insulator acting as conductor)

Comment: Your second paragraph is confusing, at least to me. What exactly is the question?

Comment: are you asking how we know if a conductor is **really** a conductor, and not just an insulator in a humid environment?

Comment: All materials will conduct. It’s just a matter of how much voltage is needed.

Comment: Ubaid Hassan that is what my question is

Comment: The simple answer to your question would be to connect the material across the battery.